# Load an instant chart from a datagridview

Tags: c#

I need to get data from a single DataGridView a distinct Chart,. This is the first time I'm working with charts, so I've researched a bit about them but couldn't find anything that could help me with this specific problem.  Here follows a screenshot of my work until now.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUqiH.png)ck.imgur.com/dfkzV.png

Comment: Yes that will be possible but to get help here you will need to provide us with a LOT more details..

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
 dataGrid.SelectAllCells();

 dataGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;

 ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dataGrid);
```

This gets you data from a data grid ...

If you wish to use MVVM pattern, you can pass the grid into the command as a parameter:

```
var dataGrid = parameter as DataGrid;
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the data, it will be in your clipboard:

```
string result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);
```

For instance...